# Migrating to opensearch 1.2

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.4.3, opensearch

I am running Elasticsearch 7.17.0 locally and moving to AWS opensearch 1.2.4

I want to take a snapshot of my elasticsaerch indexes on 7.17.0 and move it to AWS opensearch.

I have successfully took a snap shot of my elasticsearch indexes. Does anyone know how to import them to AWS opensearch?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of OpenSearch of restoring snapshots is here: https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/opensearch/snapshots/snapshot-restore#restore-snapshots

However, you'll probably run into a (in)compatibility issue, as OpenSearch can't import from ElasticSearch > 7.10, see [Upgrade from Elasticsearch to Opensearch using Snapshots in S3-Repository - OpenSearch - OpenSearch](https://forum.opensearch.org/t/upgrade-from-elasticsearch-to-opensearch-using-snapshots-in-s3-repository/10330/2?u=sebix)